# Stored Proc. parameter being dropped on one server but not on another

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a really weird issue here. I have two server setups, one here and one at a customer. The two setups are pretty alike - same OS/SQL server version etc. On our end everything is working fine, but on the customer end they were getting really weird issues. After setting up a trace and looking through it I noticed that there was a stored procedure that wasn't getting called with all the parameters it needs, where on our end all parameters where there, except one of them was an empty string ('').

So my question is - is there a configuration setting in SQL server that has to do with how stored procedures handle empty/blank parameter values? It seems the parameter is dropped completely on the customer's server.

I know about setting default values on parameters, but since I'm passing in an empty string, I would expect this to work.

Comment: Is the SP definition identical on both servers?

Comment: Completely identical. I even tried re-running the setup scripts on the customer server to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

There is no setting that affects this. There never has been.

The code (c#, other SQL, Excel, whatever) that calls the stored procedure **is** different between the 2 systems, even if the the actual stored procedure is identical.

Comment: The system is deployed on our end and theirs using the same installer so I find it difficult to see how the code should differ?

Comment: @Graffen: the code is different. There is no setting. Go and check: don't assume.

Comment: Fine, there is no setting. But the code is completely identical. That was naturally the first thing I checked yesterday when I started looking into this. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: The calling code too? Or just the stored procedure?

Comment: The calling code and the stored procedures are identical. I windiff'd the files yesterday to be sure.